# Prove complex equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Assuming $\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1}=\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}$, to prove

$$
\left|z_2-z_1\right|=\left|z_3-z_1\right|=\left|z_2-z_3\right|
$$

```
z1->p + I q;

z2->u + I v;

z3->x + I y;
```

My code：

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ComplexExpand[
  Abs[((x + I y) - (p + I q))*((p + I q) - (x + I y))] == 
   Abs[((u + I v) - (p + I q))*((u + I v) - (x + 
         I y))]] // FullSimplify
```

> $\sqrt{(p-u)^2+(q-v)^2} \sqrt{(u-x)^2+(v-y)^2}=(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2$

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[(u + I v) - (p + I q)] - Abs[(x + I y) - (p + I q)],
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // FullSimplify
```

> $\sqrt{(p-u)^2+(q-v)^2}-\sqrt{(p-x)^2+(q-y)^2}$

This expression cannot be made equal to zero by substitution.

Is there a way to solve this problem, using MMA instead of manual calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context is

> Assuming $\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1}=\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}$, to prove
> $$
> \left|z_2-z_1\right|=\left|z_3-z_1\right|=\left|z_2-z_3\right|
> $$

where $\,z_1,z_2,z_3\,$ are complex numbers. These numbers
form a triangle in the complex plane. The initial equality
assumes that the triangle is self-similar. The result is that the triangle must be equilateral. This implies the
sides are equal which is the statement to be proved.

The question is

> Is there a way to solve this problem, using MMA instead of manual calculation?

Assuming the numbers are distinct, define the quotients
$$ w_1 = \frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1}, \qquad
w_2 = \frac{z_3 - z_2}{z_1 - z_2}, \qquad
w_3 = \frac{z_1 - z_3}{z_2 - z_3}. $$
The result can be derived by Mathematica as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
w1 = (z2 - z1)/(z3 - z1);
w2 = (z3 - z2)/(z1 - z2);
w3 = (z1 - z3)/(z2 - z3);
soln = Solve[ w1 == w3, z3];
Simplify[{ 1 == Abs[w1^3] == Abs[w3^3]} /. soln]
(* {{True}, {True}} *)
```

That is, the code shows that $\,1 = |w_1^3| = |w_3^3|\,$
which implies that $\,1 = |w_1| = |w_3|\,$ and finally
$\, |z_2-z_1 |= |z_3-z_1 |= |z_2-z_3 |.$

Comment: Wow, it's so interesting! How did you come up with the idea of proving `1==Abs [w1 ^ 3]==Abs [w3 ^ 3]` instead of directly proving `1==Abs [w1]==Abs [w3]`?

Comment: @lotus2019 Because, if you do `Simplify[Abs[{w1,w2,w3}^3] / .soln]` they are all 1. That is, I knew that $w_1,w_2,w_3$ were third roots of unity.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to simplify the equation first. The equation is identical to

[image]

Without loss of generality we set `z1==0` and get the equation `z2  /z3   ==  - z3 /(z2 - z3 )`

```
eqn = ComplexExpand[ReIm[z2  /z3   ==  - z3 /(z2 - z3 )] /. { z2 -> x2 + I y2, z3 -> x3 + I y3}] // Simplify
sol3 = Solve[eqn == 0, {x3, y3}, Reals]
```

Checking `Abs[z3]` we find

```
(x3 + I y3) (x3 - I y3) /. sol3 // Simplify
(*{x2^2 + y2^2, x2^2 + y2^2}*)
```

which proves `Abs[z3]==Abs[z2]`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Some minor modifications and additions: `eqn = ComplexExpand[ReIm[z2/z3 == -z3/(z2 - z3)] /. {z2 -> x2 + I y2,  z3 -> x3 + I y3}] // Simplify; sol3 = Solve[eqn, {x3, y3}, Reals];` ,which proves `Abs[z3]==Abs[z2]`. Then `Simplify[ExpandAll@
  ComplexExpand[
   Abs[((x2 + I y2) - (x3 + I y3))] /. 
    sol3, {x2, y2, x3, y3} \[Element] Reals]]`,which proves `Abs[z3-z2]==Abs[z2]`.

Comment: @lotus2019 Thank you for completing my answer!

Comment: It's a pleasure :-)